# Get value from using key [{key: key1, value: value1}, {key: key2, value: value2}]

Tags: javascript, key-value

The result set is [{key: key1, value: value1}, {key: key2, value: value2}], what method should I use in Javascript to get the value of a particular key. Example I need the value for 'key2'. Is there a specific method or should I use a loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert that result set to an index object, and then perform all subsequent look-ups on the index object. That way you only have to iterate over the result set once.

Below is a straightforward implementation based on the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var results = [{key: "key1", value: "value1"}, {key: "key2", value: "value2"}];
var index = results.reduce(function(index, result) {
    index[result.key] = result.value;

    return index;
}, {});

alert(index.key2);
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you don't need to do multiple look-ups, but just need to extract one value, using a regular for-loop will be faster and use less memory.

```js
var results = [{key: "key1", value: "value1"}, {key: "key2", value: "value2"}];

for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
  if (results[i].key === 'key2') {
    alert(results[i].value);
    
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best idea if you want to access values consistently in larger data set. If you want to look it up only once per application runtime simple for-loop would be faster.